# How to resolve watchpack error when run Nextjs app in cpanel?

Tags: npm, next.js, cpanel, putty

I have uploaded nextjs code to cpanel and then trying to run app by `npm run dev` but I am getting following error in next js.

```
[iamuser@conebar07 public_html]$ npm run dev

> next-demo-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev -H mydomain.com -p 49000

ready - started server on nextappdomain.com:49000, url: http://nextappdomain.com:49000
info  - Loaded env from /home/iamuser/public_html/.env
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/home'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home'
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: EACCES: permission denied, watch '/home'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home'
event - compiled client and server successfully in 8s (170 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 82 ms (134 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 51 ms (36 modules)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
```

It's simple next js app. There is no additional settings added. It's working perfectly in my windows local system. Also can not find any watchpack related setting in app. Do I just need to update permission for home directory in cpanel or is there any way to change watchpack path in app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the temporary workaround. This error only occurs when I run command from cpanel terminal but if I run this command by connecting putty, it's working fine.